# How do you exclude class fields from SORM table definition?

Tags: mysql, scala, sorm

I'm persisting a class to MySQL using SORM. This class contains one or two fields that I need on the class but are not to be persisted to the DB. Does anyone know how to exclude these from the table definition?

The problem is that the type of the field is unsupported by SORM. Not a problem, as it's an actor ref and shouldn't be persisted, but there doesn't appear to be a simple way to tell SORM to just ignore it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ignore fields in SORM.

In fact it is a very bad idea from a design perspective to mix a business logic (which an actor ref definitely is) into a model. A model should be just data, nothing else. Even if SORM didn't require that, I would still recommend you to extract the actor-related logic into another object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll take another look and see if I can change the way it's set up. Great ORM btw!